# How to calculate fit between observed data and a given probability density function?

Tags: probability, optimization, density-function

Suppose I have some probability density function $f_{X}(x)$, and $N$ observed data points. How do I calculate (as a single number) how well the observed data "fits" to the given probability density function?

It would be used as an objective function for an optimization problem.

Comment: May the $N$ datapoints be assumed to be distributed iid? Separately, are you familiar with the Kolmogorov-Smirnov goodness of fit statistic?

Answer (score 1):

The usual thing to do is to calculate the surprisal: $-\sum_i \log f(x_i)$.  This is also known as the NLL loss (negative log likelihood).  In general when $x_i$ are distribution observations rather than point observations, it is cross entropy loss.  Since the data is presumed fixed with respect to learning, its entropy is constant, and so this is also the KL loss (as in it minimizes the Kullback-Leibler divergence).

You can find a list of example loss functions and justifications, including the NLL loss in [1] (section 2.2).

When I am presented with a loss function, I usually try to find insight by interpreting it as NLL loss of some unknown distribution.  In your question, you have already assumed distributions (by assuming density functions), so that doesn't apply to your question, but it's been useful to me.

[1] LeCun, Y., Chopra, S., Hadsell, R., Ranzato, M., & Huang, F. J. (2006). A tutorial on energy-based learning. In Predicting Structured Data. MIT Press.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you elaborate a little more why this works (and is used)? Is $f$ in your answer the pdf and $x_{i}$ the observed data?

Comment: @quee: Yes, I'll find some references, but it will take me a few minutes.

Comment: @quee: Hopefully, you have access to this paper.