# how to evaluate logistic regression given binary labels

Tags: regression, logistic

I've encountered an interview question:

Given several binary labels, each label represents a user will click a certain advertisement or not, we have a trained logistic model and its predicted probability of a user clicking the advertisement. How to evaluate this trained 
logistic model?

I answered by using different thresholds on the predicted probability, we can easily plot the ROC curve and then area under the curve should be a measure. 
The interviewer said that this is Okay, but can you give me other methods? I'm
wondering how to answer this question. By the way, I failed at last.

```
         click or not     predicted
user1        1               0.8
user2        1               0.6
user3        0               0.4
...         ...              ...  
usern        0               0.3
```

Comment: See: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/171300/858

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164204/how-to-compare-probability-predictive-ability-of-models-developed-from-logisti/164229#164229

Answer (score 0):

You may want you consider the log loss function to evaluate the accuracy performance of the model. Check this link out that discusses the log loss function.

https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-intuitive-explanation-for-the-log-loss-function